# Heroku local works fine but Server Error (500) with heroku open

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have now followed the [Heroku instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally) as well as [another deploy tutorial](https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/heroku/). I am able to get the app running locally when I run `heroku local` and the site looks fine. I then go for `heroku open` and I get a `System Error (500)`

My question is: a) how do I read these logs to determine the error, and b) what is some other troubleshooting when the local app runs fine but I get a server error when trying to open through the Heroku app? Thanks for any help.

Here is the tail from `heroku logs`

```
    2016-09-21T22:14:22.183850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn aptly.wsgi`
2016-09-21T22:14:25.965426+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-21 22:14:25 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2016-09-21T22:14:26.018518+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-21 22:14:26 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:6663 (3)
2016-09-21T22:14:26.018676+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-21 22:14:26 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-09-21T22:14:26.023706+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-21 22:14:26 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2016-09-21T22:14:26.092715+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-21 22:14:26 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2016-09-21T22:14:26.764197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-09-21T22:15:02.410363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=desolate-cove-94597.herokuapp.com request_id=53f43d4a-5b5c-477b-a355-39bf5156f8b3 fwd="73.163.191.79" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=223ms status=500 bytes=239
2016-09-21T22:15:28.285891+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by me@gmail.com
2016-09-21T22:15:41.534684+00:00 heroku[run.7412]: Awaiting client
2016-09-21T22:15:41.555107+00:00 heroku[run.7412]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2016-09-21T22:15:41.801070+00:00 heroku[run.7412]: State changed from starting to up
2016-09-21T22:15:44.353920+00:00 heroku[run.7412]: State changed from up to complete
2016-09-21T22:15:44.329626+00:00 heroku[run.7412]: Process exited with status 0
2016-09-21T22:16:03.086299+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createsuperuser` by me@gmail.com
2016-09-21T22:16:12.065178+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: Awaiting client
2016-09-21T22:16:12.211145+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: State changed from starting to up
2016-09-21T22:16:12.115569+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createsuperuser`
2016-09-21T22:16:47.426556+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: State changed from up to complete
2016-09-21T22:16:47.417258+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: Process exited with status 0
2016-09-21T22:17:29.613811+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=desolate-cove-94597.herokuapp.com request_id=139eb23c-3c5c-4a0d-a39d-bdcef078c5ab fwd="73.163.191.79" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=278ms status=500 bytes=239
2016-09-21T22:25:20.701742+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by me@gmail.com
2016-09-21T22:25:29.863579+00:00 heroku[run.1764]: Awaiting client
2016-09-21T22:25:29.892630+00:00 heroku[run.1764]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2016-09-21T22:25:30.117446+00:00 heroku[run.1764]: State changed from starting to up
2016-09-21T22:25:32.716060+00:00 heroku[run.1764]: Process exited with status 0
2016-09-21T22:25:32.732441+00:00 heroku[run.1764]: State changed from up to complete
2016-09-21T22:26:29.724389+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=desolate-cove-94597.herokuapp.com request_id=7dc56798-101e-4e89-b4d6-5b892c2175c8 fwd="73.163.191.79" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=219ms status=500 bytes=239
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand why the 500 error. But my initial thought is your local and remote is not fine.  Can you confirm there is no database involve to render the `/` view function ?

Comment: @F'inAwesome correct, no database involved.

Comment: Then it must be very hard to debug...! Do you setup any environment variable in local that needs to be update in heroku as well